# get photo using ID returns false

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I refer to this topic posted on the facebook forums

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=105044

Why would it return false? How do you retrieve a photo from and album you just uploaded to via the Graph API? Is this a bug?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the uploaded photo from Graph API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7327452/get-the-uploaded-photo-from-graph-api)

Comment: No it is not! totally different question but it is related to the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have an answer for you but if you post the photo and change the privacy settings to public, it should work.